# delete \ in column of obejct when covert to json pandas python

Tags: python, json, excel, python-3.x, pandas

i have dataframe User

```
id | user  | phone
------------------
1  | chris | {"device": "a", "brand": "a"}
2  |  nat  | {"device": "a", "brand": "a"}
3  | zack  | {"device": "a", "brand": "a"}
```

then pass it to object variable

```
rows = df.loc[df['id'] == 1]
merged = {'data': rows.reindex(columns=df.columns.values).to_dict('records')}
with open((path + '/' + filename + '.json'), 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(merged, fp)
```

then got filename.json :

```
{
  "data": {
    "id" : 1,
    "user" : "chris",
    "phone": "{\"device\": \"a\", \"brand\": \"a\"}"
   }
}
```

expected result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id" : 1,
    "user" : "chris",
    "phone": {
        "device": "a", 
        "brand": "a"
     }
   }
}
```

how to make it as expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of `phone` is already JSON. Converting JSON to JSON will lead to escaping the quotes, as you are experiencing.

The solution is to turn the JSON string of `phone` to a `dict` first using `json.loads`), before you convert `merged` to JSON.

```
import json

merged = {
  "data": {
    "id" : 1,
    "user" : "chris",
    "phone": "{\"device\": \"a\", \"brand\": \"a\"}"
   }
}

merged['data']['phone'] = json.loads(merged['data']['phone'])

print(json.dumps(merged, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "user": "chris",
        "phone": {
            "device": "a",
            "brand": "a"
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that `phone` is always valid JSON, otherwise `json.loads` will fail.